# BX.ready is not a function / BX is not a function

Tags: javascript, битрикс, консоль

[image: Проблема с js библиотеками в ядре битрикса]

Вероятно ошибки так же влияют на то что, в режиме правок на странице отсутствует возможность редактирования компонентов

Comment: Вероятно, стоит галка "Переместить весь Javascript в конец страницы:", но до него подцепляется блок скриптов с ошибкой.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)